# Image Data passed to automl_classifier in Azure Machine Learning python SDK runs into EmptyDataException Error

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to run **azure automl on my local PC** (MacOS Catalina: 10.15.6) in conda environment with the setup mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-environment#local

The aim is to find the best model and parameters using azure automl for binary **color** image classification.

**Training Data Sample:**

```
train_data_img = train_data.copy()
for index in tqdm(train_data.index):
    img_file = train_data_img['image_file'][index]
    image = cv2.imread(img_file)
    img_resized = cv2.resize(image, (256, 256))
    img_numpy = np.array(img_resized)
    train_data_img['np_image'][index] = img_numpy

print(train_data_img.head())
type(train_data_img)
```

> ```
>                                                np_image  y
> 474   [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], ...  0
> 2121  [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], ...  0
> 1836  [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], ...  1
> 94    [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], ...  0
> 663   [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], ...  0
> ```
>
> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

**Code to run automl in local PC:**

```
automl_classifier=AutoMLConfig(
    task='classification',
    primary_metric='AUC_weighted',
    experiment_timeout_minutes=5,
    blocked_models=['XGBoostClassifier'],
    training_data=train_data_img,
    label_column_name=label,
    n_cross_validations=2)

from azureml.core.experiment import Experiment

ws = Workspace.from_config()

# Choose a name for the experiment and specify the project folder.
experiment_name = 'automl-classification'
project_folder = './sample_projects/automl-classification'

experiment = Experiment(ws, experiment_name)

run = experiment.submit(automl_config, show_output=True)
```

> ```
> ~/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azureml/automl/runtime/training_utilities.py
> ```
>
> in _extract_user_data(user_script)
> 2211         raise EmptyDataException(
> 2212             "Get data script was not defined and X,"
> -> 2213             " y inputs were not provided.", has_pii=False)
> 2214     try:
> 2215         output = user_script.get_data()         # type: Union[Dict[str, Any], Tuple[Any, Any, Any, Any]]
>
> ```
> EmptyDataException: EmptyDataException:
>   Message: Get data script was not defined and X, y inputs were not provided.
>   InnerException: None
>   ErrorResponse 
> {
>     "error": {
>         "code": "UserError",
>         "inner_error": {
>             "code": "InvalidData",
>             "inner_error": {
>                 "code": "EmptyData"
>             }
>         },
>         "message": "Get data script was not defined and X, y inputs were not provided."
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: just wanted to confirm with you that you have populated the 'label' variable - hope it is not null

Comment: @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT the label variable is a string with value "y". The values of train_data_img["y"] is of type np.int64 .